# search for a column that has a keyphrase in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table with a `keyphrase` column. Given a string I need to find all rows in the table that the keyphrase is contained in the string.

For example:

- I have a row in the table with the **keyphrase** `a test`.
- I then have a **string**: `Hello this is a test string`
- I need a query using that string to find all rows with a matching
  keyphrase.

I thought `ILIKE` would do the trick but I think I need to do the opposite.

Comment: How is this question related to Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  *
from    KeyPhraseTable kp
where   'Hello this is a test string' ILIKE '%' || kp.keyphrase || '%'
```

Comment: Can you explain whats going on here so I can learn it better? Thanks.

Comment: It select rows containing keyphrases from a table, and for each row, tries to match them with your test string

Comment: What do the `||` do?